# Android apps localization in a country

Tags: android, google-play

The android market allows developers to customize the title, descriptions in about a dozen languages. Now, how does Google decide which languages to show for which country?

Some of them are straight forward - like using English for US or Australia. But how about options for both French and English in France? Or Spanish or English in Spain? Which is the default language used?

I couldn't find out as to where it is specified, if it is so. Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: it does. thanks and sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the OS language specified in settings=>Language & Keyboard. For instance i have a phone in Japan, that i can use with both English and Japanese.I can see the different descriptions. titles etc in Google Play when i switch the language.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For more informations see the section **How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource** in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Comment: I think the question is asking about how Google Play(android market) chooses the right language  to show the correct resource(title,desc) thats been added in the developer console when publishing the app.